# Name Mashup Program Improvement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and trying to solve different problems i came across this program which is name mashup which is in Get Programming:Learn to code with Python.

problem statement: Write a program that automatically combines two names given by
the user. That’s an open-ended problem statement, so let’s add a few more details and restrictions:

- Tell the user to give you two names in the format FIRST LAST. Show the user two possible new -names in the format FIRST LAST.
- The new first name is a combination of the first names given by the user, and the new last name is a combination of the last names given by the user.

  For example, if the user gives you Alice Cat and Bob Dog, a possible mashup is Bolice Dot.

I'd like to know is there any way to improve this program like using functions to make this program better.

```
    print('Welcome to the Name Mashup Game')

name1 = input('Enter one full name(FIRST LAST): ')
name2 = input('Enter second full name(FIRST LAST): ')

space = name1.find(" ")                    
name1_first = name1[0:space]
name1_last = name1[space+1:len(name1)]
space = name2.find(" ")
name2_first = name2[0:space]
name2_last = name2[space+1:len(name2)]
# find combinations
name1_first_1sthalf = name1_first[0:int(len(name1_first)/2)]
name1_first_2ndhalf = name1_first[int(len(name1_first)/2):len(name1_first)]
name1_last_1sthalf = name1_last[0:int(len(name1_last)/2)]
name1_last_2ndhalf = name1_last[int(len(name1_last)/2):len(name1_last)]

name2_first_1sthalf = name2_first[0:int(len(name2_first)/2)]
name2_first_2ndhalf = name2_first[int(len(name2_first)/2):len(name2_first)]
name2_last_1sthalf = name2_last[0:int(len(name2_last)/2)]
name2_last_2ndhalf = name2_last[int(len(name2_last)/2):len(name2_last)]

new_name1_first = name1_first_1sthalf + name2_first_2ndhalf
new_name1_last = name1_last_1sthalf + name2_last_2ndhalf
new_name2_first = name2_first_1sthalf + name1_first_2ndhalf
new_name2_last = name2_last_1sthalf + name1_last_2ndhalf

# print results
print(new_name1_first, new_name1_last)
print(new_name2_first, new_name2_last)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you're doing essentially the same thing (even if it's in different orders) to different values, it's a strong clue that the values should be a collection (like a list or tuple) rather than independent named variables.  It'll usually make your code a lot shorter, and it makes it much much easier to extend -- what if you wanted to play the mashup game with more names?

```
from itertools import permutations
from typing import List

print('Welcome to the Name Mashup Game')

names = [
    input('Enter one full name(FIRST LAST): ').split(),
    input('Enter second full name(FIRST LAST): ').split(),
    # input('Enter third full name(FIRST LAST):' ).split(),  <- try me!
]

def mash(first: List[str], second: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    """
    Produce a list where each element has the first half of the corresponding
    element from the first list and the second half of the corresponding 
    element from the second list.

    For example:
        mash(['AA', 'BB'], ['XX', 'YY']) -> ['AX', 'BY']
    """
    return [
        a[:len(a)//2] + b[len(b)//2:]
        for a, b in zip(first, second)
    ]

for first, second in permutations(names, 2):
    print(' '.join(mash(first, second)))
```